# Typescript : how to create a type from a javascript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a type or an interface with typescript from a javascript object that I don't know how it's created.

for example I want to create a type Request to use it in my function so I can make sure I pass the right parameter to the function :

```
let req = require("somewhere"); // my javascript object

function myfunction(request : Request) {
// some code
}

myfunction(req);// ok
myfunction(20);// Error

how can I create the Request type
```

Comment: You need to know in advance how the "javascript object" looks like, otherwise you can not create a type for it

Comment: @NitzanTomer my read of the question is how to make the parameter type and the required type covary

Comment: its an object that is created using the function constructor http.IncomingMessage (nodeJs) its has a lot of properties

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` keyword.

```
function myfunction(request : typeof req) {
// some code
}
```

Though be careful, if `req` is `any` you won't receive the type checking you want.

---

That said, if you want to access the request interface defined in express I believe you can access it as follows

```
import express = require('express')
function myfunction(request : express.Request) {
// some code
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want something visible without using typeof

Comment: In that case I feel your question is unclear. Are you asking what type to use for the interface that you imported? If that's what you'd want you'll need to tell us exactly what you're importing and exactly how you're using it.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want, what I import is the request object defined in the expressJS library, as I said it has a lot of properties

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I updated the answer, does that work for you?